# Independent t-test

Tags: mathematical-statistics, t-test

There are 2 individual groups. Group 1= 40 dental students. Group 2= 4 faculty members (who are the assessors). To compare their scores on the 'Likert Rating scale', regarding the use of rubrics, can we use the Independent t-test?

Comment: These two groups do seem independent, so there is that, but since this is Likert scale (and you have only 4 units for the assessors) a Mann-Whitney test might be more appropriate.

Comment: It probably matters what you mean by "scale".  If that's a single Likert item, or a scale composed of many questions.  In either case, make sure you understand the assumptions of the *t*-test.  Also consider that the hypothesis tested by a *t*-test is different than that of a Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney test.  There are a variety of tests to compare two groups with a variety of hypotheses tested.